# Azure Machine Learning SDK V2 changer version of python in Compute Cluster

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ai

In SDK V1, I am using a environment for compute cluster with a dockerfile string like this:

```
azureml_env = Environment("my_experiment")
azureml_env.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(
    pip_packages=["pandas", "databricks-connect==10.4"],
)
dockerfile = rf"""
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu22.04:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN apt-get -y update \
&& apt-get install  openjdk-19-jdk -y \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
"""
azureml_env.docker.base_image = None
azureml_env.docker.base_dockerfile = dockerfile
```

So I am using `mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu22.04:latest` where it gives me a python 3.8.

But when I switch to SDK V2, I get a python 3.10, which is not compatible with my `databricks runtime` that need python 3.8.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu22.04:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install  openjdk-19-jdk -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt

# set command
CMD ["bash"]
```

I call it like this in python:

```
azureml_env = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(
        path="deploy/utils/docker_context", # Where is my dockerfile and other file to copy inside
    ),
    name="my_experiment",
)
azureml_env.validate()
self.ml_client.environments.create_or_update(azureml_env)
```

Why don't I get a python 3.8 but a python 3.10?

Comment: What are the files you have inside `deploy/utils/docker_context`. You have conda yaml file?

Comment: Indeed I do have an `environments.yaml` file, but I don't use it. I have a `pip.conf` and I `requirements.txt` that I copy into the dockerfile. And indeed the yml file has python3.10 inside it. I will try to use only this yml file with a different python version. Thank you.

Comment: @JayashankarGS, I changed the dockerfile to remove the `pip install -U requirements.txt` and changed the yml file to python3.8. But it does not install any python packages. Do I have to change my dockerfile to take into account the yml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide a `conda.yaml` file when using a Docker build context. Thus, you need to create a conda environment and a Dockerfile as shown below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu22.04:latest

WORKDIR /

ENV CONDA_PREFIX=/azureml-envs/sklearn-1.0
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=$CONDA_PREFIX
ENV PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH

# This is needed for MPI to locate libpython
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Create conda environment
COPY conda_dependencies.yaml .
RUN conda env create -p $CONDA_PREFIX -f conda_dependencies.yaml -q && \
    rm conda_dependencies.yaml && \
    conda run -p $CONDA_PREFIX pip cache purge && \
    conda clean -a -y

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install openjdk-19-jdk -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt

# Set command
CMD ["bash"]
```

Here, I am creating a conda environment first with Python version 3.8 and running the remaining commands.

`conda_dependencies.yaml`

```
name: pydata-example
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip=21.2.4
  - pip:
    - numpy==1.22
    - scipy==1.7.1
    - pandas==1.3.0
    - scikit-learn==0.24.2
    - adlfs==2021.9.1
    - fsspec==2021.8.1
```

```py
env_docker_context = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(path="docker-contexts/tst"),
    name="docker-context-example-1",
    description="Environment created from a Docker context."
)
ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_context)
```

Output:

[image]

And in the environment:

[image]

If you want to avoid these commands, you can try using other images with Python 3.8.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It worked like a charm. I still find it weird that in V1 we can do thing with the SDK that we can not do with the V2. It's very confusing while trying to migrate everything

Comment: Glad it worked. I'm still trying to find what is the reason