# Azure ML custom command component - how to use a custom image

Tags: azureml-python-sdk, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

All examples that I have seen of the use of the `command_component` decorator to create custom components in Azure ML pipelines use an `image` from Microsoft's container registry, as seen in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-component-pipeline-python?view=azureml-api-2) Microsoft tutorial page and pasted below.

However, I was wondering if, and how, can we use a custom built image here?

My goal is to use an image with MS-SQL ODBC drivers installed. I tried mentioning a locally built image (on the cpu compute) in the `image` argument, but it errored out looking for a registry. I also tried using an image I had pushed to Azure Container Registry but that didn't work either as I don't know how to send credentials to this decorator.

```
# Converts MNIST-formatted files at the passed-in input path to training data output path and test data output path
import os
from pathlib import Path
from mldesigner import command_component, Input, Output


@command_component(
    name="prep_data",
    version="1",
    display_name="Prep Data",
    description="Convert data to CSV file, and split to training and test data",
    environment=dict(
        conda_file=Path(__file__).parent / "conda.yaml",
        image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04",
    ),
)
def prepare_data_component(
    input_data: Input(type="uri_folder"),
    training_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
    test_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
):
    convert(
        os.path.join(input_data, "train-images-idx3-ubyte"),
        os.path.join(input_data, "train-labels-idx1-ubyte"),
        os.path.join(training_data, "mnist_train.csv"),
        60000,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an environment object with a custom `Dockerfile` context like below:

```py
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment, BuildContext
environment = Environment(build=BuildContext(path="docker_context"))

@command_component(
    name="prep_data",
    version="1",
    display_name="Prep Data",
    description="Convert data to CSV file, and split to training and test data",
    environment=environment,
)
def prepare_data_component(
    input_data: Input(type="uri_folder"),
    training_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
    test_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
):
    convert(
        os.path.join(input_data, "train-images-idx3-ubyte"),
        os.path.join(input_data, "train-labels-idx1-ubyte"),
        os.path.join(training_data, "mnist_train.csv"),
        60000,
    )

def convert(imgf, labelf, outf, n):
    f = open(imgf, "rb")
    l = open(labelf, "rb")
    o = open(outf, "w")

    f.read(16)
    l.read(8)
    images = []

    for i in range(n):
        image = [ord(l.read(1))]
        for j in range(28 * 28):
            image.append(ord(f.read(1)))
        images.append(image)

    for image in images:
        o.write(",".join(str(pix) for pix in image) + "\n")
    f.close()
    o.close()
    l.close()
```

Here, in `environment = Environment(build=BuildContext(path="docker_context"))`, the `docker_context` is the folder containing the `Dockerfile` and dependencies like `conda_dependencies.yaml` and `requirements.txt`.

In the `Dockerfile`, add your custom Docker commands to install MS-SQL ODBC.

For more information about building the custom image, refer to this [Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022405/azure-machine-learning-sdk-v2-changer-version-of-python-in-compute-cluster/78026532#78026532) and the [command_component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.entities.commandcomponent?view=azure-python#constructor) class for more information on environment arguments.